# because usestate in component doesn't work, what to do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a usestate in the component folder there I will use the usestate, but it does not render the app and the message is as follows: (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') to which the component I import and render in app.tsx , what can I do to resolve this?

```
import * as C from './style';
import LupaImage from '../../assets/lupa.png';
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

const [searchProduct, setSearchProduct] = useState('');

const handleSearchProduct = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setSearchProduct(e.target.value)
}

export const ResearchField = () => {
  return (
    <C.ResearchField>
      <C.Logo src={LupaImage} />
      <C.InputSearch placeholder='Busque pelo Produto' />
    </C.ResearchField>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `useState` within the component and `handleSearchProduct` function either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is`useState` can be used inside a component only.

The solution could be

```
 //move this state into a component if you want to useState()
 //something like this

import * as C from './style';
import LupaImage from '../../assets/lupa.png';
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

export const ResearchField = () => {

const [searchProduct, setSearchProduct] = useState('');

const handleSearchProduct = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setSearchProduct(e.target.value)
}

  return (
    <C.ResearchField>
      <C.Logo src={LupaImage} />
      <C.InputSearch placeholder='Busque pelo Produto' />
    </C.ResearchField>
  )
}
```